# Rotating one vector to face another but slowly?

Tags: math, language-agnostic, vector, rotation

I have two vectors: `heading` and `target`.  How can I turn heading to face target by some factor?  Say 10% every frame or something.

*community edit:* **The `target` vector is constantly changing.**

Thanks!

Comment: This question is too vague. Do you want to turn by constant angular rate (e.g. one degree each second), or in some other way? Does the magnitude of your heading mean anything? etc.

Answer (score 3):

Find the angle between the two vectors using the dot product:

```
heading . target = |heading|*|target|*cos(theta)
```

Then every frame, rotate `heading` by `0.10*theta` using the rotation matrix.

Comment: This assumes you have some sort of rotation matrix though. In 2D this is a well defined operation, but in 3D it becomes ill defined.

Comment: It is perfectly well-defined in 3D as "the matrix which rotates by theta along a rotational axis".

Comment: How do you choose the specific rotational axis though? I remember trying to solve this exact problem recently but I don't remember what the solution to this was. (On an unrelated note, I probably shouldn't be trying to do math at 3 in the morning)

Comment: for 3D, the rotational axis can be selected with the cross product between heading and target (`a x b` will be some vector orthogonal to both `a` and `b`)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the only thing that matters is the direction of `heading` and `targetHeading`, we will assume all vectors are normalized. You have also said that you would like this to be true:

```
dheadingDegrees/dt = angle(targetHeading,heading) degrees/sec in the direction of targetHeading
```

(At least that's how I interpret it, as opposed to "gets closer by 10% every frame but never reaches the destination")

To get an exact answer you'd need integration and some math. If you want to simulate it and get a precise answer, you probably want to decouple this from the "frames" and simulate it maybe 100 intervals per second, depending on the required accuracy.

Thus:

```
every time interval dt:
 target = getCurrentTarget()
 rotationSpeed = angleBetween(target,currentHeading)/(1second)
 heading = {rotate heading by dt*rotationSpeed radians towards target}
            ^-------- for how to do this, see below ----------------^

to rotate a vector v1 to v2 from time t=0 to t=1, with constant angular velocity:
 v1normalized = normalized(v1)
 v2perpNormalized = normalized(v2 - v2*v1normalized)
 animated = cos(t*pi/2)*v1normalized + sin(t*pi/2)*v2perpNormalized
```